I need a universal function for code in python, similar to permutation/combination, have code example
Here's the code example:
res = []
for i in game.keys():
    for j in game.keys():
        if f'{i}{j}' not in res and f'{j}{i}' not in res:
            res.append(f'{i}{j}')
print(res)

I need this, but it should work for not only 2, but 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 arguments (I wonder if there's a function that returns this and takes arguments like permutation and combination, so function(table_Of_Arguments, number_Of_Elements)). I could write my own function in the above way, but I think there should already be something like that.
I've done some research and many people recommend permutation or combination from itertools, but permutation returns too much (it returns both {i}{j} and {j}{i}) and combination returns too little (it doesn't return cases where i==j). I will be using it with table_Of_Arguments of size 32, so I hope there is something more optimized than my code, because 32^7 is a pretty high number.

you mean several nested loops ?   what have you tried in the itertools module and where does it fail ?  please show a worked example.

itertools.permutations ?

you can certainly write your own function, but it is most likely that you are replicating itertools or similar without knowing that you have done so...

You want itertools.combinations_with_replacement

You could make this code vastly faster by having res be a set instead of a list.  It may also help to have the elements of res be frozensets - that way, you only have to do one check to detect any ordering of the components.

Is this a duplicate? Finding all combinations of a list in Python with repetition. The answer has the solution you want, but OP there seems to be confused about what they want, so I don't blame you if you say it's not the same.

Please write a more descriptive title. If I understand what you're asking, it could be "How can I get combinations allowing repeats?" See [ask] for tips on that.

Could you give an example with three arguments? With two, it's hard to tell what f'{i}{j}' and f'{j}{i}' mean (forwards/backwards vs all permutations).

@MichaelCao Might as well write that as an answer!

Does this answer your question? Number list with no repeats and ordered

You want itertools.combinations_with_replacement
